# Run Laravel Vite Vue.js build without Artisan

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, laravel-9, laravel-vue

I am a newbie learning `Vue.js` and I am using it with Laravel. I have decent experience with Laravel. Previously, without any frontend setup, I simply used to go to `http://localhost/my-project/public` and my Laravel homepage would display as everything used to be in the public directory.

Now I am using `Vue` with `Vite` as my build tool. After running `npm run build`, the build assets by `Vite` are placed inside `public/build` directory. I run the dev environment using `npm run dev` and `php artisan server` and I can access the app on `http://localhost:8000` but how do I access my app without using Artisa or without any dev servers running?

This is my `/public` directory structure:

```
│   .htaccess
│   favicon.ico
│   index.php
│   robots.txt
│
├───build
│   │   manifest.json
│   │
│   └───assets
│           app.5bcb0e65.js
│           app.dd96aa6d.css
            ..other images, fonts
```

Currently, When I go to the URL `http://localhost/my-project/public/dashboard`, I see nothing but a blank white screen and an error in the console saying `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/my-project/public/dashboard"` but with php artisan server, I can access `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` without any issues.

This is my `routes\web.php` file contents:

```
...

Route::any('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::any('/{slug}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('slug', '([A-z\d\-\/_.]+)?');
```

Comment: once you're ready to ship, run the following command ``npm install && npm run build`` in the root folder of the project.

Comment: Did it. Actually, I am not having difficulties creating a production build, instead, I want a way to access that production build. The production build is placed inside `public\build` folder by vite but how do I access the resources without artisan? When I go to the URL `http://localhost/my-project/public/dashboard` I see nothing but a blank white screen and an error in the console saying `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/my-project/public/dashboard"` but with php artisan server, I can access `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` without any issues.